# Does a view need to be init with a frame and then have auto-layout change it or just use auto-layout?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a custom view that I have implemented and I am trying to learn how to use auto-layout without the use of the storyboard.

My question is do I need to init my view with a frame, or can I just do an empty init and then use auto layout to have the view figure out the width and height by itself?

Below you will see that I have tried adding the frame and then putting the auto-layout thinking that I have to put a frame first and then auto-layout changes it.

```
let origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 44.0)

let frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)

customView = ExpandableHeadingView(frame: headingFrame)

customView.frame.size.height = 44.0

view.addSubview(customView)

view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.topAnchor).isActive = true
view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't set the frame. You just need to set enough constraints for autolayout to be able to set it for you.

One thing you're missing that may be a problem is:

```
customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

If you're creating a view in code, you generally need to set this manually to be able to properly use it with autolayout.

Comment: I did what you suggested, but it is still not working. I have added this `customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0)` hoping that this would get it to show up, but nothing is there. I even debugged the view and the constraint doesn't show up. Any thoughts on why the height constraint doesn't work? I have a left, right, and top set so the height should take care of the last bit in my mind.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not working? What's actually happening? And I also see you already had a height constraint set before: `view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.heightAnchor).isActive = true`. Did you remove this one?

Answer (score 2):

If you are overriding the init method on a custom UIView subclass (the one that receives a frame as its only argument) you will have to give it a frame when creating it in a ViewController. What you can do is give it an empty frame and the with AutoLayout set its proper constraints for position and size. For example:

```
class CounterView: UIView {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      backgroundColor = .red
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

And in the view controller:

```
private var counterView: CounterView = {
  let view = CounterView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
  return view
}()
```

.....

```
view.addSubview(counterView)
counterView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
counterView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
counterView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: standardSpacing).isActive = true
counterView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

That code produces this:

[Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Evg.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to layout your view with auto layout, don't use this constructor.

```
UIView(frame: CGRect)
```

Simple init your view with

```
UIView()
```

And main mistake that you are doing, is that you are setting those anchors to controllers view, but you need to set them to your view,that you created, like so..

```
let customView = UIView()
customView.backgroundColor = .blue
customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addSubview(customView)

customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
customView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
customView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

And you are good to go.